# Filter columns of a dataframe between a range using a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|       Total_Production                      Utilization_rate         Avg_Count   |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 0            6.503907                      96.027778                26.194017    |
| 9            6.171308                      95.638889                31.500943    |
| 18           6.144897                      95.986111                27.494776    |
| 27           6.056882                      95.916667                27.525495    |
| 36           6.107343                     105.541667                21.500208    |
| 45           2.139576                      96.166667                27.480307    |
| 54           6.161222                      96.486111                27.498256    |
| 63           1.034555                      56.388889                27.568885    |
| 72           5.021524                      91.069444                30.931702    |
| 81           5.831919                      96.277778                28.284872    |
| 90           2.689860                      62.486111                18.691440    |
| 99           5.227672                      95.555556                31.441761    |
| 108          1.465271                      95.541667                30.064098    |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The range is in two series.
Highest Range:
Total Production                    7.744379
Utilization rate                  104.534796
Avg Count                          29.691733

Lowest Range:
Total Production                    3.880623
Utilization rate                    64.315015
Avg Count                           22.652148

What is the best possible way to filter out data of columns?
Can i do it using a for loop by iterating rows?

Answer (score 14):

You can use the [`&` operator](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) to limit the ranges of individual columns:

```
df[ 
  (3.880623 < df['Total_Production'])  & (df['Total_Production'] < 7.744379) &
  (64.315015 < df['Utilization_rate']) & (df['Utilization_rate'] <  104.534796) &
  (22.652148 < df['Avg_Count'])        & (df['Avg_Count'] < 29.691733)        
]
```

Answer (score 9):

You could use `query`

```
In [233]: df.query('3.880623 < Total_Production < 7.744379 and 64.315015 < Utiliza
     ...: tion_rate <  104.534796 and 22.652148 < Avg_Count < 29.691733')
Out[233]:
    Total_Production  Utilization_rate  Avg_Count
0           6.503907         96.027778  26.194017
18          6.144897         95.986111  27.494776
27          6.056882         95.916667  27.525495
54          6.161222         96.486111  27.498256
81          5.831919         96.277778  28.284872
```

Comment: Can't get better than this. Most efficient I guess.

Comment: But seems like it is the slowest of 3 :). Check the timings in my answer.

Comment: Yep. `query` and `eval` methods work well on larger objects.

Comment: Can we achieve this using `all()` method?

Answer (score 3):

```
def foo():
    df[ 
  (3.880623 < df['Total_Production'])  & (df['Total_Production'] < 7.744379) &
  (64.315015 < df['Utilization_rate']) & (df['Utilization_rate'] <  104.534796) &
  (22.652148 < df['Avg_Count'])        & (df['Avg_Count'] < 29.691733) ]

def foo1():
    df[df.Total_Production.between(left=3.880623, right=7.744379) &
       df.Utilization_rate.between(left=64.315015, right=104.534796) &
       df.Avg_Count.between(left=22.652148, right=29.691733)]

def foo2():
    df.query("3.880623 < Total_Production < 7.744379 and 64.315015 < Utilization_rate <  104.534796\
    and 22.652148 < Avg_Count < 29.691733")

%timeit foo()
%timeit foo1()
%timeit foo2()
```

Output:

```
100 loops, best of 3: 2.95 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.92 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.67 ms per loop
```

Comment: Is this achievable by using a for loop by iterating rows? The highest and the lowest range is in two different series.

Comment: Didn't get you. What do you mean by two difference series?

Comment: And yes you can iter through the rows. There are various iter methods available on dataframe. If you are using Jupyter or IPython press tab after `df.iter` to see the various available methods.

Comment: Highest Range is in one series and lowest range is in one series. Thats what i said.